# Expression for external magnetic field of a cylindrical bar magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I would like to calculate the magnetic force of a cylindrical bar magnet on a steel ball bearing, which is a distance away in a straight line from one of its poles. What is the expression for this?

Ultimately would like to find the work done on the ball bearing due to magnetic force.

Comment: How could you calculate the work done? We don't know if the bearing can move or not, how far can it be moved etc. The force itself is not sufficient info. If it's mantled to something, it's not gonna move and hence the work is zero.

Comment: the bearing can move, just wanted to do a very basic, inaccurate,  calculation by taking the dot product of force and the distance between the pole of the magnet and the bearing.

Comment: But the force will change as the bearing moves towards the magnet, so you would have to integrate over this path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it it is a very hard task to calculate the force. Just to outline the steps as they came to my mind:

1. Find the magnetic field around a cylindrical bar magnet. (You need to have some input, though, such as the magnetization inside). I'm afraid there is no simple expression for it but it can be calculated numerically: see [arXiv:0909.3880](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3880) or this [wolfram demo](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MagneticFieldOfACylindricalBarMagnet/).
2. Find the magnetic permeability $\mu=\mu_0(1+\chi)$ of the material (or its susceptibility $\chi$) [note that this is not a very good description for feromagnets, however], find the magnetic field inside the bearing so that the Maxwell equations $\nabla\cdot \vec B = 0$ and $\nabla \times (\vec B / \mu) = 0$ are fulfilled inside, outside and *on the border* od the steel body.
3. Calculate the magnetic force by integrating $ \vec F = \int\nabla( \vec M \cdot \vec B) = \frac{\chi}{(\chi+1) \mu_0 }\int \nabla(B^2)$ over the volume of the bearing.

Comment: A picture would help.  The answer depends on the orientation and the relative sizes and distances.